# Test MySQL Connection with default Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm wondering if there is any built-in way in Python to test a MySQL server connection. I know I can use PyMySQL, MySQLdb, and a few others, but if the user does not already have these dependencies installed my script will not work? How can I write a Python script to test a MySQL connection without requiring external dependencies?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no built-in support for MySQL - the only relational support included in the Python library is from the SQLite database.

Comment: @holdenweb You should expand that slightly and make it an answer. As it stands, it is the best answer to this question (unless a suitable dupe target is found).

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python distributions do not include support for MySQL, which is only available by installing a third-party module such as `PyMySQL` or `MySQLdb`. The only relational support included in Python is for the SQLite database (in the shape of the `sqlite3` module).

There is, however, nothing to stop you distributing a third-party module as a part of your application, thereby including the support your project requires. `PyMySQL` would probably be the best choice because, being pure Python, it will run on any platform and give you best portability.